# SQL Query to exclude rows with similar but not identical values

Tags: sql, vertica

I need to find only unique car insurance calculations in a table. In this case ***rows are not unique if calculations were done in less than five minutes one after another in the same day, by one company, on an identical car***.

The problem is, all of them are done one by one with different id's and only thing I can get from DataBase is time and date of Calculations, name of the company that have made them,model,brand and production year of the car.

To be more specific, table I have looks like this:

```
|   Time_Date  | company | year | model | brand  |
|--------------|---------|------|-------|--------|
|20.08.16 15:31|    A    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan |
|20.08.16 15:34|    A    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan |
|20.08.16 15:38|    A    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan |
|20.08.16 16:02|    A    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan |
|20.08.16 15:36|    B    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan |
|20.08.16 15:37|    B    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan |
|21.08.16 15:33|    A    | 2015 | Teana | Nissan |
```

And what I need to get:

```
|  Time_Date   | company | year | model | brand  |
|--------------|---------|------|-------|--------|
|20.08.16 15:31|    A    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan |
|20.08.16 16:02|    A    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan |
|20.08.16 15:36|    B    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan |
|21.08.16 15:33|    A    | 2015 | Teana | Nissan |
```

Database I use is Vertica.
Can, please, anyone suggest the solution? It seems like not a big problem, but I kinda stuck :(

P.S.

If there is a record at 15:31 , then there is a record with same company, year, model at 15:34 it should not be in the final table, and if after that there is another calculation in less than five minutes after the last in a row of calculations similar to 15:31, than it should not be in a final table too. So in this case 15:31,15:34,15:38 are the same and 16:02 is different.

Comment: Without a schema I cannot write the query for you, but this should help : https://blog.jooq.org/2015/05/12/use-this-neat-window-function-trick-to-calculate-time-differences-in-a-time-series/

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please be careful when tagging your questions. Vertica <> sql server and the correct answer will be specific to your database.

Comment: record with time 15.38 isn't in the  final results.  Why? It's more than 5 minutes from 15:31.  If we had the same record as 15:31 but with a time of 16:02 would it appear in results (I think it should given requirements)?  The sample data provided fails to show the problem correctly. Put simply this question lacks necessary details to address; including proper sample data.

Comment: @xQbert Hi, yes, i'm soryy, i should've mentioned it. If there is a record at 15:31 , then there is a record with same company, year, model at 15:34 it should not be in the final table, and if after that there is another calculation in less than five minutes after the last in a row of calculations similar to 15:31, than it should not be in a final table too. Answering your question about 16:02 it shouldn't be excluded, because its time is motre than five minutes after 15:38. 
So in this case 15:31,15:34,15:38 are the same and 16:02 is different.

Answer (score 0):

Rextester doesn't have a Vertica environment so I can't test the below.

Here's a working SQL Server version http://rextester.com/FWK58234  (edge cases needed to be tested a bit more)

The syntax seems "close" to SQL Server with the only needed to add ticks around mi in the datediff function (added below)

Use a common table expression (CTE) and Analytic LAG (look back at prior records value) to determine the datediff for each company year model brand partition.  Then eliminate all those records with a datetime difference <= 5 but keeping all those with a null datediff (implying it's the first record in the lag series) and those greater than 5 minutes as they denote a unique record.

Note: my example results vary because I added additional data to help edge test.

```
WITH CTE as (
   SELECT Time_date
        , company
        , year
        , Model
        , Brand
        , datediff('mi',Lag(time_Date,1,NULL) over (partition by company, year, Model, Brand ORDER BY time_date asc),Time_Date) as MinuteDiff
   FROM foo)

   SELECT Time_date, company, year, Model, Brand, MinuteDiff
   FROM CTE
   --We need those with a NULL Minute Difference since they denote the 1st entry for a company, year model brand
   --we also need those with a minute difference > 5
   WHERE MinuteDiff > 5 or minutediff is null
   ORDER BY  Company, Year, Model, Brand, Time_date
```

*Note if a Time_date record existed for a company, year model and brand such that there was an entry every 5 minutes for the course of 3 days, only 1 record would be returned.  A single gap in that would return 2 records (baring the gap being the 1st or last entry)

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked for me. I came up with a solution also, but it is not so good as yours, speaking of memory. I thought, that I could join table on itself by company, year,brand,model, and two conditions on time  : the first time less than other and timediff is less than five minutes. So i can have a list of duplicate rows and than exlude them from my table:)

Comment: I honestly thought about a self join but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.  This is why I ended up with the above.  At first I thought this was overkill looking at your data set I thought the break was on day, but after re-reading the text I realized you had a 5 minute rolling variance. that we needed to account for.  That's when I realized we needed some way of looking back at a prior record time_date sorted by time_date and partitioned by company and car; thus lag().

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
;With cte(  Time_Date  , company , year , model , brand  )
AS
(

SELECT '20.08.16 15:31',    'A'    , 2014 , 'Teana' , 'Nissan' UNION ALL 
SELECT '20.08.16 15:34',    'A'    , 2014 , 'Teana' , 'Nissan' UNION ALL 
SELECT '20.08.16 15:38',    'A'    , 2014 , 'Teana' , 'Nissan' UNION ALL 
SELECT '20.08.16 15:36',    'B'    , 2014 , 'Teana' , 'Nissan' UNION ALL 
SELECT '20.08.16 15:37',    'B'    , 2014 , 'Teana' , 'Nissan' UNION ALL 
SELECT '21.08.16 15:33',    'A'    , 2015 , 'Teana' , 'Nissan' 
)
SELECT Time_Date,   company,    [year], model,  brand FROM
  (
SELECT DISTINCT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY company,model,[year] ORDER by Time_Date,company ) dst FROM cte 
 )Dt
Where dst=1
Order by [year]
```

Result

```
Time_Date      company  year    model   brand
------------------------------------------
20.08.16 15:31  A       2014    Teana   Nissan
20.08.16 15:36  B       2014    Teana   Nissan
21.08.16 15:33  A       2015    Teana   Nissan
```

Comment: Overkill In my opinion.  and fails do address the 5 minute variance issue.

Comment: `Distinct` is useless when `Row_Number` is part of `Select`

Comment: @Srini131 . Hello! Thank you for your answer! I use window functions in my everyday work to solve problems with duplicates, as you did, but this case is different, I edited the text of a problem, so I would be grateful, if you have thoughts on that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT MIN(Time_Date) AS Time_Date, company, year, model, brand 
FROM Vertica.dbo.yourTable 
GROUP BY company, year, model, brand
```

Comment: Others answered while I was typing.  I apologize for the duplication.  Moving on...

Comment: @xQbert, the query I wrote will give you a distinct list of company, year, model, brand with the Minimum Time_Date...

Comment: I think we're all wrong.  None of us is addressing the 5 minute lag issue.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, my query does address the issue and removes duplicates.  The 5 minute lag issue is what is creating duplicates. 
 Does the specific time matter?  Maybe I'm wrong, but that's how I understood the issue.

Comment: Lets say there was a record with a time_date of 16:02  on 20.08.16 that had a company A year 2015, model Teana and brand Nissan.  Your query would exclude it.  I think the requirements indicate it would be wanted

Comment: @xQbert, according to the "And what I need to get:" result set, my query would be corerect.  However, if you focus on the way the question was written, then you'd be correct.  However, then the "And what I need to get:" result set is the original question would be wrong as there is a 7 minute lag between "20.08.16 15:31|    A    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan" and "20.08.16 15:38|    A    | 2014 | Teana | Nissan" and only the Minimun date was included.  So, I suppose the question wasn't clear enough... Cheers.

Comment: @DataDad thank you for your answer, but it's not, I understand I didn't stated my question well.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to implement using the (Vertica) Analytic Function **CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT**.

First I have created a temp table `mutable` containing your data:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE mytable (time_date, company, year, model, brand)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
    SELECT '2016-08-20 15:31:00'::timestamp(0),'A',2014,'Teana','Nissan' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-08-20 15:34:00'::timestamp(0),'A',2014,'Teana','Nissan' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-08-20 15:38:00'::timestamp(0),'A',2014,'Teana','Nissan' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-08-20 16:02:00'::timestamp(0),'A',2014,'Teana','Nissan' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-08-20 15:36:00'::timestamp(0),'B',2014,'Teana','Nissan' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-08-20 15:37:00'::timestamp(0),'B',2014,'Teana','Nissan' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-08-21 15:33:00'::timestamp(0),'A',2015,'Teana','Nissan' ;
```

Then you just have to:

```
SELECT
    MIN(time_date) AS time_date, 
    company, year, model, brand
FROM (
    SELECT
        time_date, company, year, model, brand, 
        CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(time_date - LAG(time_date) > '5 minutes')
             OVER (ORDER BY time_date) AS cce
    FROM mytable
     ) a 
GROUP BY cce, company, year, model, brand
;
      time_date      | company | year | model | brand  
---------------------+---------+------+-------+--------
 2016-08-20 15:31:00 | A       | 2014 | Teana | Nissan
 2016-08-20 16:02:00 | A       | 2014 | Teana | Nissan
 2016-08-20 15:36:00 | B       | 2014 | Teana | Nissan
 2016-08-21 15:33:00 | A       | 2015 | Teana | Nissan
(4 rows)
```